# Using feature extraction for OCR

Tags: python, opencv

I am using SIFT feature extraction for OCR.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img1=cv2.imread('/Users/amuly/Desktop/Soap/training data/d000.jpg')
img_temp=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img2=cv2.imread('/Users/amuly/Desktop/Soap/test/dot matrix/5.jpg')
img_scene=cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kps1, descs1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img_temp, None)
kps2, descs2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img_scene, None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.knnMatch(descs1,descs2,k=2)
print matches

#Apply Ratio test

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
print good

# Draw matches which is giving me an error

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kps1,img2,kps2,good,None,flags=2)
```

Error is

> Expected cv::DMatch for argument 'matches 1to2'

I am having matches in `good[]` which is then passed in `drawMatches()`.

```
plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Tried to format the question better, but I have no idea what " I am having something in good" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kps1,img2,kps2,good,None,flags=2) instead and it should work.